# Execute matlab script from ubuntu terminal but getting error "matlab: command not found"

Tags: matlab, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed matlab 2018a I want to execute matlab script from ubuntu(18.04 LTS) terminal. Matlab installation path is "**/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a**". Now I run : **matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/siddhartha/Documents/matlab_code/test_matlab_script.m');exit;"** to execute test_matlab_script.m script.

The script contain :

```
clear all;
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = a+b;
disp(c);
```

but I am getting error **matlab: command not found**
[image]

Please help me in how to overcome this error and successfully execute the matlab script from terminal

Comment: You probably don't have /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin (or whatever the bin directory is under that installation) in your PATH.  At least in the past when I was running the Matlab installer it would give you the option to add some links in a more standard place like /usr/local/bin.  Anyway, you can either add the bin directory to your path or just explicitly run /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab ... (fix the path  as necessary according to where matlab is).

Comment: So you are saying instead of typing : matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/siddhartha/Documents/matlab_code/test_matlab_script.m');exit;"  I should type : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/siddhartha/Documents/matlab_code/test_matlab_script.m');exit;"

Comment: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/siddhartha/Documents/matlab_code/test_matlab_script.m');exit;" is working . But the drawback is to open matlab and to exit matlab it is taking time which I dont want. Is there any way to get rid of that?

Comment: If your script is so fast that opening and exiting Matlab is a bottleneck, maybe you can do whatever the task is in some other language.  Possibly Python with numpy and related libraries would be a good fit.  Otherwise I suppose you could write a little server in Matlab, leave it running, and have a lightweight client program that would just send scripts to the Matlab.  I know Matlab has some TCP/IP functionality in the Instrument Control Toolbox.  Or you could have Matlab  just polling for something like a script to appear in a known file.